# Unit test for a function with random inside. Javascript

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I have this random function. how can i create an unit test for this ? (Must use Jest)

```
random = (array) => {
    for(let val of array){
        var change_percent = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1001) + -500)/100; // random a rumber from -5 to 5
        val.change_percent = change_percent;
        val.volume = val.volume + Math.floor(Math.random()*(20) + 10); // random increase volume from 10 to 30
        val.price = (parseFloat(val.price) + parseFloat(val.change)).toFixed(2);
        val.change = (val.price * change_percent /100).toFixed(2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the result of function is random, there is no way to predict the correct answer. But you can set an interval(range) of acceptable values. Just like this:

```
test('get random number in range [0, 20]', () => {
    const result = random();
    expect(result).toBeGreaterThanOrEqual(0);
    expect(result).toBeLessThanOrEqual(20);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply mock `Math.random` like this :

```
global.Math.random = () => 1
```

so `random([{change_percent: 2, volume: 2, price: 2, change}])` will give you an result that can be easily be tested.

Note as all test run independently from each other overwriting `Math.random` will not interfere other tests.